# My mouse randomly disconnecting and reconnecting.Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, mouse

After the latest windows 10 update,my mouse for no reason keeps disconnecting and reconnecting and also it makes windows usb unplug/plug sounds.This is so annoying,I can't even play a game correctly.My right arm hurts from this..

Someone told me that I need to reinstall its drivers..but I m not really sure,what to do.I would appreciate some help ASAP.

Mouse : Logitech M90

Comment: sure its not the mouse? It feels like hardware failure of some sort to me

Comment: Are you using the default Microsoft drivers for the mouse, or crazy Logitech drivers and apps?

Answer (score 13):

Things to try:

### I. Disable automatic USB suspend

1. In [Device Manager](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000833.htm), find your mouse under the heading "Human Interface Devices".
2. Right-click, select Properties.
3. Go to the Power Management tab.
4. Make sure "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is **unchecked**. If it's checked, like in the screenshot below, **uncheck it**. 
   [image: Power Management tab]
5. Repeat Steps 1-4 for the "HID-compliant mouse" under "Mice and other pointing devices". If you have more than one "HID-compliant mouse", that means you either have a game controller connected or some other mouse-like device, or your mouse exposes multiple  HID devices; in this case, you will need to do Steps 1-4 for *each* of them  (just to be safe).
6. If the above steps don't help, do the same procedure for each device under "Universal Serial Bus controllers" heading. If one or more of the devices listed doesn't have a Power Management tab, don't worry about it; just skip over it. **Note:** this step may reduce the battery life of a laptop significantly, and very slightly increase the energy consumption of a desktop/laptop plugged into A/C power (the increased power drain will have a negligible effect on your electric bill, but you may notice the reduced battery life on battery power).

### II. Update your motherboard chipset drivers and BIOS/firmware

For this step, you must know your exact motherboard make and model, *or* your computer's serial number if it's a pre-built system from a vendor like Dell, HP, Lenovo, etc.

Since you didn't state any of the relevant information, all I can do is provide general purpose instructions.

#### II(a). Instructions for Chipset/Firmware Update if you have a pre-built computer

(A pre-built computer is where a company assembled it for you and you opened the box with all internal components installed in the desktop/laptop)

1. Find your Service Tag and/or Serial Number sticker somewhere on the case or chassis of your desktop/laptop. If you have both a Service Tag and a Serial Number, you'll probably need both.
2. Go to the main support website of your PC manufacturer.
3. Enter your Service Tag, Serial Number, Model Number, or any other information the manufacturer requests about you or your PC.
4. Go to the driver downloads section of the support website.
5. Find any drivers under the headings of "Chipset", "Motherboard", "USB", etc. and download the *latest* version available, making sure it says it's compatible with Windows 10. **Very important:** If the release date of the driver is *before* approximately August 2015, this probably means the chipset driver **will make the problem worse**, because these drivers are *older* than Windows 10 itself, and will be even less-suited to your system than your current drivers. What we're looking for are drivers that are *newer* than the release of Windows 10, indicating some kind of post-release driver update.
6. Download and install the drivers. The exact steps are extremely specific to the driver in question, but the general process is to extract/unzip as necessary, then run setup.exe or whatever .exe appears most likely to be the main installation executable. When in doubt, read the README file.
7. After installing any chipset drivers that seem relevant, look for a "Firmware", "BIOS Update", etc. heading in the driver downloads section for your PC. If you haven't ever previously updated your BIOS/firmware, there is almost certainly going to be an update available. Make sure you download an updater that says it will run on Windows; some manufacturers release BIOS updates in the form of a bootable floppy disk or USB thumb drive image, but there is also usually a Windows .EXE (in a ZIP file, perhaps) that you can run and it's much more convenient.
8. Once you've downloaded your BIOS update, close *all* open programs and run the BIOS updater. Let it reboot your PC when it asks to and heed all warning dialogs (e.g., make sure your laptop is connected to A/C power), then be patient as it upgrades your system BIOS / firmware.

#### II(b). Instructions for Chipset/Firmware Update if you have a custom-built computer

Here you must know the exact model number of your motherboard. If you don't know, look for the box the motherboard came in, or look on the receipt from the vendor you purchased it from or the vendor that custom-built your computer for you.

You can also conveniently identify most motherboards using [Piriform Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy) (the free version works fine). The motherboard make and model should be displayed on the Summary page as soon as you open the program after installing it.

**Note:** If you have a pre-built computer and are able to positively identify your motherboard as a "retail" motherboard (that is, a motherboard that is sold separately on the market at websites such as Amazon or Microcenter), you can try the below steps to potentially get a newer version of the drivers / firmware than what may be available on the pre-built computer's manufacturer's website. Do this at your own risk, however, as the PC manufacturer *could possibly* have customized the motherboard in a way that makes generic retail drivers incompatible with it (this is more likely with laptops).

1. Visit the support website of your motherboard manufacturer.
2. Search for or browse for the exact model of motherboard that you have. Don't go for something that's "close" but not exact, because BIOS/firmware updates are *extremely* motherboard-specific, and installing the wrong one can brick your system if the update utility isn't smart enough to check for the right motherboard before updating.
3. Look for a driver heading called "Chipset" or "motherboard" or "USB", and download the *latest* associated drivers. Extract and install them. Make sure they are compatible with Windows 10 and newer than the release date of Windows 10 (approximately August 2015), otherwise they are unlikely to provide any benefit.
4. Look for a BIOS or UEFI Firmware update section, and download the *latest* firmware updater *for Windows* (ignoring any .iso or .img files that require you to burn them to a CD or load them onto a thumb drive or floppy).
5. Close all programs and run the BIOS/Firmware updater, allowing it to reboot when prompted and heeding all warning dialogs (e.g., make sure your laptop is connected to A/C power).

### III. Mouse drivers

I looked up your mouse, Logitech M90, on [Logitech's website](http://support.logitech.com/en_roeu/product/mouse-m90#download). All they offer is the SetPoint software, which isn't actually a *driver*; all SetPoint does is let you *customize* the button mappings of your mouse. So it is exceedingly unlikely to provide any benefit in terms of making sure your mouse is working correctly.

You can still download and try it as a last resort, though.

### IV. Isolating whether it's the mouse hardware or a particular USB port or controller

1. Try a different USB port, if available. Plug your mouse into another USB port, or swap your mouse and another USB device to see if the other USB device now starts disconnecting itself when connected to the original port your mouse was plugged into. This step can be particularly revealing when you try USB ports from different USB *controllers*. For example, on a desktop, most motherboards use a different USB controller for the front panel USB header and the back panel.
2. Try a different mouse, if possible. Ask a friend if you can borrow another USB mouse. If it exhibits the same problem after trying the above steps, then you know that your M90 mouse is not at fault. If the problem goes away, the most likely issue is that your M90 is somehow damaged (the cord, the USB connector, the circuitry inside the mouse, etc.)

### V. Isolating whether it's Windows

1. Go to http://ubuntu.com and download the .iso image of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04. Burn it to a DVD or flash it to a USB thumb drive or SD card (whichever medium is most convenient for you). Ubuntu has instructions on their website for how to burn or flash the ISO image [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows).
2. Boot up your new Ubuntu live environment and select "Try Ubuntu" when prompted (don't install it unless you know what you're doing; installing Ubuntu is outside the scope of these instructions).
3. Use your computer like normal for a while. Start up Firefox and surf the web a bit. Use it long enough until you're confident that your mouse certainly would've disconnected itself by now if you were running Windows. Do you still  have the problem? If the problem **goes away**, then your issue is definitely related to a Windows program or driver. If you haven't gone through sections I and II of this answer yet, reboot into Windows and do that now.
4. If the problem **still exists**, it's either a hardware problem or a BIOS problem. There is also a tiny, *tiny* chance that both Ubuntu and Windows have exactly the same software problem, but that is so vanishingly unlikely that I wouldn't consider it at all, personally.

If you've gone through all these steps and determined that the problem is with Windows, and steps I through III didn't solve the problem with Windows, then more in-depth troubleshooting is necessary than what I can provide in a generic answer.

Answer (score 3):

My USB mouse disconnecting issue took me a few weeks to solve.
It was caused by my USB powered miniature fan that was use to cool the laptop.
The answer is EMS or Electro Magnetic Interference/pulse.
Try to switch off all lights and all electronic devices in order to test and to check the "problematic USB mouse".
Thank You

Comment: Wow. Like, omg wow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. First make sure your mouse usb cable works properly on other devices, Like smart TV or plug it on an android phone by OTG.
2. Download Latest Driver from official website

http://support.logitech.com/en_nz/product/mouse-m90-product/downloads#windowsPnlBar

Answer (score 0):

The "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" for a USB mouse has to be disabled in:
"Universal Serial Bus controllers"
"Mice and other pointing devices"
"Human interface Devices"

Additionally under "Human Interface devices" I have found multiple instances of:
"Logitech HID-compliant Unifying device"
and "USB Input Device"

when only one was connected,

and under "Mice and other pointing devices"
there was:
"HID-compliant mouse"
and "Logitech HID-compliant Unifying device"

disabling the duplicates under "Human Interface devices" and the "HID-compliant mouse" under "Mice and other pointing devices" has dramatically reduced my problems which were presumably due to conflicts.