# My mouse disconnects when not touching a surface, and lags to start moving the mouse, but will work pefectly fine till I pick it up to move it

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse, wired

I'm having a problem trying to get my mouse to work. It will just sound like it's connecting and disconnecting when it's not on something, and when I put it back down it takes a moment to work(Thank god I have a touchpad), and then jolts to a spot and does all the actions before. But works completely fine afterwards, until I pick it up again.

Steps and what happens:

1. Plug in.(wired)
2. Makes connect sound.
3. Put the mouse on a surface.
4. Start moving mouse but nothing happens.
5. Mouse on screen jolts to where the movements would take it.
6. Works perfect.
7. Pick up and turn over.(Here down happens if within short time of plugging in)
8. The light on the bottom is randomly/frequently flickering and disconnecting/reconnecting.(Flickers even without being done in short time)
9. Sounds stop, light turns off, go to Settings > devices. The I get this, on the bottom right>[Mouse "Disconnects" Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea2bU.png)

Here's an image of device manager

When done in short time:
[image: When done in short time]

When done after a while:
[image: When done after a while]

It's a normal dell mouse, that has worked since I got it 1-2 years ago. I have looked at some other questions too, talking about Logitech mice messing up, seams to be the same problem, but nothing works. [My mouse randomly disconnecting and reconnecting.Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1122912/my-mouse-randomly-disconnecting-and-reconnecting-windows-10)
[Why is my USB mouse disconnecting and reconnecting randomly and often?](https://superuser.com/questions/53740/why-is-my-usb-mouse-disconnecting-and-reconnecting-randomly-and-often)

Devices: HP Laptop(can't find model), Dell Mouse(nothing special about it), Logitech Artemis G933, Steam Controller(don't know if it might have something to do with it)

Answer (score 1):

It definitely sounds like the mouse is defective.  Perhaps there is a loose solder joint, improperly connected wire, bad electronics, or something along those lines.

If you have another computer, try this mouse on it and see if it behaves the same way.  If it does, its definitely defective.  The fact your touchpad is working, makes me believe your computer is fine.

There is nothing special about a Dell mouse, as they are cheap, but usually well made.  Toss this mouse in the trash and just purchase a new mouse.  For the average user, a $10 mouse is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. Thankfully I had multiple extra mice around(just preferred that one because it's not so bulky, and no problems, till now at least). I'm just using my other dell mouse, one of the most common ones you see, it works perfect, but the left click requires a bit of a push. Any idea?